# The image element in footer is showing default picture and not the original one

Tags: html, css

The image here in footer is not showing in live server rather it is coming up as alt.

```css
.footer {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer"> Made with **
  <img src="/assets/prograd-heart.svg" alt="heart">** by Yash </footer>
```

Comment: What is "default picture"? Do you mean the broken path icon?

Comment: broken path? check your dev tools / network for any 404s

Comment: Are you sure that set a correct path?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes i mean the broken path icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably used the wrong path.

You should know:

`.` means **current directory**

`..` means **parent directory**

Try one of these:

```
<img src="assets/prograd-heart.svg" alt="heart">** by Yash </footer>

<img src="./assets/prograd-heart.svg" alt="heart">** by Yash </footer>

<img src="../assets/prograd-heart.svg" alt="heart">** by Yash </footer>
```

Comment: Yes it worked , i used the wrong path thanks a lot